# linear transformation relative to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I am self-learning linear algebra and I get stick on the Linear transformation from a vector space to itself.

My book (linear algebra and its application 4th edition) say that
$$[T(x)]_{\beta} = [T]_{\beta}[x]_{\beta}$$
Where T is the the linear transformation which map x->T(x). As you can see, this is a differentiation operation)

The example it shows is

The mapping $T: P_2 \to P_2$ is defined by
$$T(a_0 +a_1t_1 + a_2t_2) = a_1 + 2a_2t$$

a/ find the $\beta-matrix$ for $T$ when $\beta$ is the basis for $\{1,t,t^2\}$

I have had a problem in understanding this, $a_0 +a_1t_1 + a_2t_2$ isn't a vector and also the basis $\beta$. $1,t,t^2$ are just scalars so why $(a_0 +a_1t_1 + a_2t_2)$ can be treated as a vector to apply into a linear transformation. Also, the basis $\beta$ for $\{1,t,t^2\}$ doesn't make sense for me.

This problem is mentioned on page 290 of linear algebra and its applications 4th edition David C.Lay

Comment: What's your understanding of $P_2$?

Comment: I think $P_2$ is a vector space

Comment: No, not **a** vector space, but a rather well-known, *specific* vector space. You must know this otherwise the exercise is almost pointless

Comment: well, at the point I am right now, the book has just mentioned about linear transformation which mapping a vector in a domain to its codomain and linear transformation from a vetor space to another vector space. Also the chapter I am reading is right after the chapter about vector space so I think it must be vector space since the topic I am right now is about it.

Comment: But has the book explained what's meant with $P_2$?

Comment: It doesn't explain since vector space is the only answer of $P_2$, I think

Comment: p. 192, Chapter 4. Example 4.

Comment: thank, but it is still unclear to me, I mean $(a_0+a_1t_1+a_2t_2)$ just a number but not a 3x1 matrix as the example in chap 4, $P_2 = \{a_0+a_1t_1+a_2t_2\} for any t and a. You have that book, so can you explain it to me clearly.

Comment: Well, there's a publicly available copy [here](http://digtro.com/skule/ressurser/lay_linear_algebra_4th-e_txtbk.pdf). The basic idea of $P_2$ is the following: Firstly, we don't consider $t$ as a fixed value, but a independent variable. The elements of $P_2$ are not numbers, but they are _functions_. As such, they behave similarly to vectors: The sum of two such functions is a polynomial of degree 2 or less again, and if you multiply one  with a scalar, you again end up with such a polynomial. In this case, you can identify $t \mapsto a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2$ with the vector $(a_0,a_1,a_2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write, in some kind of matrix algebra with algebraic entries,

$$a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2=[1,t,t^2]\begin{bmatrix}a_0\\a_1\\a_2\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$T(a_0+a_1t^1+a_2t^2)=a_1+2a_2t=[1,t,t^2]\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\2a_2\\0\end{bmatrix}=[1,t,t^2][T]_β\begin{bmatrix}a_0\\a_1\\a_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank for explaination but I have one more question, from what I have learn that the transformation matrix of an linear transformation is left multiple by the variable but why in &T(a_0+a_1t^1+a_2t^2)& the transformation matrix is between two matrix, it seems strange to me and &t,t^2$ are not fixed value so it seems different from other basis I have seen.

Comment: $1,t,t^2$ are vectors in this context, the basis vectors of the space of degree 2 (or less) polynomials. You usually do not see the basis matrix of Cartesian space with its canonical basis since that would be the identity matrix.